# Use cases for detached threads

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, posix

In case of detached threads, if the main thread finishes executing before the detached thread, this would terminate the process killing all the threads. pthread_join() doesn't work in for detached threads.

So in what scenarios are detached threads used because I should be sure that detached thread has finished execution before terminating the process?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you care whether the thread has finished execution? What you care about is whether any work that you need done has been done. If you use some other way to track what work is done, you don't need to wait for the thread to finish execution.